# Azure AD Application session

Tags: azure-active-directory

Have couple of questions with respect to how Azure AD session works

If have couple of web applications registered in my AAD tenant. The users of these application can be MSA, organization account with AAD or Federation account. All these accounts will be Guested in the AAD tenant where the applications are registered

1. if i logout from Azure Portal, can i prevent logout from my Application? Assume that the account is same for Azure Portal and AAD application
2. If i logout from my application 1, can i prevent logout from Azure Portal asking for password from application 1 if i try to access it again?
3. I read that application and Azure AD cookies are stored in browser. Can i see them? What are the name of these?
4. Is it possible to force the user to enter the password for particular application, if the user is inactive in that application

Comment: "if i logout from Azure Portal, can i prevent logout from my Application?" - please elaborate. Are you using the same MSA for your org AAD account _and_ for accessing the Azure portal?

Comment: "I read that application and Azure AD cookies are stored in browser." - this is an oversimplification and is not universally true. Because JWTs tend to be huge (over 2KB) many people store them in a server-side cache (e.g. Redis) and only issue a short _reference-token_ to them instead - and things get complicated when you factor-in things like ASP.NET's ClaimsPrincipal cookies. Anyway, in all cases the cookies are encrypted with a server-side secret so you cannot actually peek inside them unless you're debugging your application locally or have a remote debugger attached.